# jquery toggle <td> on click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table that has a few items inside, and a button for each that will display more information on the specific item on the menu.

my HTML table is below

```
<table id="menu_breads">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">BREADS</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>ITEM</th>
            <th>PRICE</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Portugese Rolls
                <button class="myButton">&#x2C5</button>
            </td>
            <td>R1.49</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="more">A hand made selection of Portugese rolls</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hotdog Buns
                <button class="myButton">&#x2C5</button>
            </td>
            <td>R0.99</td>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="more">A hand made selection of Hotdog buns</td>
            </tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>French Loaf
                <button class="myButton">&#x2C5</button>
            </td>
            <td>R3.49</td>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="more">A hand made selection of French loaves</td>
            </tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sead Roll
                <button class="myButton">&#x2C5</button>
            </td>
            <td>R2.49</td>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="more">A hand made selection of Seed Rolls</td>
            </tr>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                 <h6>Prices may change without prior warning</h6>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
<!-- TABLE FOR CONFECTIONARIES -->
<table id="menu_confect">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">CONFECTIONARIES</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>ITEM (per slice)</th>
            <th>PRICE</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Cream Slice
                <button class="myButton">&#x2C5</button>
            </td>
            <td>R12.49</td>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="more">A hand made selection of Cream slices</td>
            </tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Chocolate Cake
                <button class="myButton">&#x2C5</button>
            </td>
            <td>R15.99</td>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="more">A hand made selection of Chocolate cakes</td>
            </tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Coconut Eclaire
                <button class="myButton">&#x2C5</button>
            </td>
            <td>R2.49</td>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="more">A hand made selection of Coconut Eclairs</td>
            </tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Chocolate Eclaire
                <button class="myButton">&#x2C5</button>
            </td>
            <td>R4.49</td>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="more">A hand made selection of chocolate Eclairs</td>
            </tr>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                 <h6>Prices may change without prior warning</h6>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

My CSS is here

```
.myButton {
    background: #183C4C;
    border-radius: 31%;
    border:2px solid #4e6096;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:11px;
    text-decoration:none;
    width: 15%;
    float: right;
}

.more {
    display: none;
    }
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/aozjzahv/)

and the jquery is what I am having a bit of a problem understanding. Would I need to ID every td that I want to display or can I do it with classes and an on click toggle event?

I have managed to get it to display on click, the problem is that all the hidden rows display and not just the individual one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.myButton').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').next().find('.more').toggle();

    if ($(this).closest('tr').is(":visible")) {
                $(this).html("&#x2C4")
        }
        else { 
            $(this).html("&#x2C5")
        }
});
```

});

Comment: You can do it with class's, add your jQuery to the question. What you will be looking for tho is `$(this)` so it affects the class that was clicked and not all of them.

Comment: The problem with hiding a cell that it it can have an undesired effect; [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0nc946jx/). I would recommend hiding ether a column, or a row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wouldn't have to give IDs to every `td`, that'd be overkill. You want something dynamic. Assuming that your HTML structure will stay the same, you can do:

**EDIT: Added the ability to toggle plus and minus icons from comments**

```
$(".myButton").on("click", function () {
    var more = $(this).closest("tr").next("tr").find(".more");
    more.toggle();

    if (more.is(":visible")) {
       //show minus icon, hide plus
    }
    else {
       //show plus icon, hide minus
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t376d55w/) (**thanks Rory**)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Hehe just! Used your fiddle link, gave you the credit :)

Comment: Just a notice: i would use data- attributes to link two elements together, because with this solution the next time you change your markup the script will not find anything. For example data-more="productID" and <td class="more" data-productDescriptionFor="productID"

Comment: What a legend! Thank you so much! This is perfect!

Comment: @DevinGray No problems, glad I could help!

Comment: Just out of interest sake if I wanted my arrow to change to an up arrow on this function would I use an if/ else like so?, updated in the question

Comment: @DevinGray Check my updated edit, see how I check if it's visible? That way we can toggle arrows/plus minus icons etc. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, it is my second week with jquery and this is helping alot to understand.

Comment: @DevinGray You'll get there, happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
$(".myButton").on("click",function() {
   $(this).closest("tr").toggle();
})
```

Comment: That will hide itself. From his specifications I don't believe this is what he is after.

Comment: I still don't believe that's what he is after. That will hide the next row. Though others agree with your assertion. Completely fine with being wrong here.

Comment: I agree with you, he propably wants to hide the whole row.

Comment: I believe that hides its own row.

Comment: `$(this).closest('tr').next().toggle();` is suitable.

Answer (score 1):

The `more` should be given to the tr - also your markup is not valid(you have a `tr` as child of `tr` - the `more` tr is child of the button `tr`)

```
    <tr>
        <td>Portugese Rolls
            <button class="myButton">&#x2C5</button>
        </td>
        <td>R1.49</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="more">
        <td colspan="2">A hand made selection of Portugese rolls</td>
    </tr>
```

then

```
$('.myButton').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').next().toggle();
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ard9nb51/)

---

If you don't want to change anything

```
$('.myButton').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').next().find('.more').toggle();
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ard9nb51/2/)